# Name of the barkeeper in Ghost in the Shell: SAC?

Tags: ghost-in-the-shell-sac

In S1E4, "INTERCEPTOR," we see the Major in a bar. The barkeeper is bald, has several piercings, wears a red vest, and speaks with a strange soft tone. What's the name of the barkeeper?

Scene in question is at 16:20.

Comment: In the original anime he is not named, but in the dub the Major calls him something like Veradimo or Heradimo.